# Swagger API filtering doesn't seem to work

Tags: java, swagger

I've written some fancy code to play around with Swagger API filtering:

```
public class ApiAuthorizationFilterImpl implements ApiAuthorizationFilter {
    @Override
    public boolean authorize(String apiPath, String method, HttpHeaders headers, UriInfo uriInfo) {
        System.out.println("authorize");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean authorizeResource(String apiPath, HttpHeaders headers, UriInfo uriInfo) {
        System.out.println("authorizeResource");
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then I've extended my `web.xml` file with these lines:

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>swagger.security.filter</param-name>
    <param-value>mypackage.rest.utils.ApiAuthorizationFilterImpl</param-value>
</init-param>
```

But this doesn't seem to work. Whenever I call my REST methods, there are neither stops in debugger in `ApiAuthorizationFilterImpl` nor lines printed.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The filtering will apply to the documentation, not the method invocation itself.  See if hitting the swagger documentation resource directly (i.e. http://{your-server}:8080/user.json) and you should see the printlns emitted.

To secure the methods themselves, you would write a separate filter, or share the logic across the swagger and invocation filter.